# How to configure react-router-dom, react-router-redux in index.js?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is my index.js. The problem is that Chackout route doesn't show on its own, insted I have '/' route and /chackout route on the same page. I tried everything, but nothing works because I can't send my states from redux to checkout component.

I have tried using HashRouter insted Router, and changing history to hashHistory inported from history package. Problem stays the same, I can just render redux store on the same page as my home component but not in the CheckoutContainer component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {Route, Router} from 'react-router'
import {routerMiddleware, syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer, ConnectedRouter as RouterR} from 'react-router-redux'
import {HashRouter, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
import {createHashHistory} from 'history';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import reducer from './reducers'
import {
  fetchAllDummyItems,
  fetchContainerId,
} from './actions'
import App from './containers/App'
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme'
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'
import CheckoutContainer from './containers/CheckoutContainer'

let hashHistory = createHashHistory()

const history = createHistory()
const middlewareRoute = routerMiddleware(history)

const reducers = combineReducers({ register: reducer, router: routerReducer })

const middleware = [
  thunkMiddleware,
  promiseMiddleware({
    promiseTypeSuffixes: ['REQ', 'ACK', 'ERR'],
  }),
];


if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  middleware.push(createLogger());
}

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
   applyMiddleware(...middleware)
 )

const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  textField: {
    focusColor: '#9fa5a8',
  },
})

store.dispatch(fetchAllDummyItems())
store.dispatch(fetchContainerId())
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutContainer} />
      </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display CheckoutContainer in the   `path="checkout"`, you should use the exact bool in the  component - [here.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)

Also another thing is that if you always want to render 1 component at a time you should also use the  componenet - check [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)

Answer (score 0):

Much easier to use React hooks to pass data and states between components no matter unrelated these components are in their hierarchy

Comment: Can you show me your data structure and type, then I use see how to demo it to you?